# Какой стиль программирования лучше?

Tags: java

Какой код лучше?
Использование return() в каждом условии:

```
void someProc(String str) {
    if (str.length < 1) {
        log("bad length");
        return();
        }
    if (str.charAt(3) == "N") {
        log("N at 3");
        return();
        }
    parse(str);
}
```

или вложенные условия без return():

```
void someProc(String str) {
    if (str.length < 1) log("bad length");
    else if (str.charAt(3) == "N") log("N at 3");
    else parse(str);
}
```

Что лучше для производительности?

Comment: Но Дейкстра бы первый вариант не одобрил, конечно )

Comment: Я бы в первую очередь задумался а лучше ли вообще эти коды? :-)
Лучше для понимания то наверное что то типа такого: 

    boolean checkConstrains(String str)
    {
        if(str.length < 1) log("bad length");
        if (str.charAt(3) == "N") log("N at 3");
    
        return !((str.length < 1)&&(str.charAt(3) == "N"))
    }
    
    void someProc(String str) {
        if(checkConstrains(str))
          parse(str);
    }

И манипулировать с вариантами оптимизации будет попроще.

Comment: очень интересная логика:

    return !((str.length < 1)&&(str.charAt(3) == "N"))

если длина меньше **единицы**, давайте ещё проверим **третий** символ, а если длина больше, то не будем=)

Comment: Ай, ай! обшибся! надо || вместо &&

Comment: при условии, что функция `log` возвращает `false`, можно было написать простой и лаконичный код:

    boolean checkConstrains(String str)
    {
        return (str.length > 0 || log("bad length")) && (str.charAt(3) != "N" || log("N at 3"));
    }

Comment: Вообше, имхо, намного лучше построение методов такого типа с семантикой `"check constraints and throw if invalid"`. Поскольку логгер, `false` и прочие вещи здесь не очень смотряться.

Answer (score 6):

Если мне не изменяет память во времена С (когда java то-ли вообще не было, то ли еще была мало распространена) существовало то ли правило/паттерн, которое гласило, что из метода может быть только одна точка выхода.

Поэтому все методы имели примерно такой вид:

```
public boolean updateList(Object a, List<Object> list)
{
   boolean updated = false;
   if (null !=list)
   {
       if (null != a && (a instanceof SomeObject))    
       {
            list.add(a);
            updated = true;
       }
   }

   return updated;
}
```

Возможно, это была крайность, к которой прибегли после того, как наелись де..ма с операторами `goto`. Ведь поведение `return` в методах `void` аналогично использованию оператора `goto`.

С популяризацией java, соотношение людей, которые читают код к тем, которые его пишут увеличивается. Поэтому сейчас более важно писать еще и легко читаемый код. Поэтому я считаю, что такой вид более приемлем:

```
public boolean updateList(Object a, List<Object> list)
{
   // can't do much more
   if (null == list)
   {
        return false;    
   }

   // nothing to add to the list
   // object is null or has invalid type    
   if (null == a || !(a instanceof SomeObject))
   {
       return false;    
   }

   // update list, return result
   list.add(a);
   return true;
}
```

Всегда пишу код в подобном стиле потому что:

1. мне его удобно читать;
2. коллеги еще ни разу не жаловались;
3. комментарии разбивают код на легко-читаемые, логически связанные группы (попробуйте добавить комментарии к предыдущему примеру, они затеряются в коде, особенно если форматирование с открывающей скобкой в той же строчке);
4. легко отследить логику метода;
5. если вы пишете документацию, а конкретно unit test plan то подобная структура кода подсказывает какие тест-кейсы надо добавить (ну и порядок).

Стоит добавить, что любая программа/метод сначала проверяет аргументы, а потом уже работает с ними. И не всегда проверка аргументов - это часть логики программы/метода, - есть смысл разделить их.

Answer (score 2):

Дело не в производительности, а в логике. Варианты отличаются по смысловой нагрузке.

Когда вы пишете:

```
if (a) { }
elseif (b) { }
else { }
```

это равносильно нижеследующему:

```
if (a) { }
else { 
  if (b) { }
  else
}
```

Т.е. проверка второго условия (и выполнение соответствующего блока) возможна, только если первое условие ложно. В этом случае, конечно, можно сказать о приросте производительности на какую-то долю в долгом цикле.

Answer (score 2):

Есть замечательное правило: верните результат, как только вы его получили. Оно позволяет избегать вложенных циклов, делает код проще и понятнее.

Comment: А есть правило что выход из функции должен быть тоже один. Я бы сильно поспорил что множество return'ов делает код проще и понятнее. Всё хорошо в меру.
Ваше правило может и позволит избежать вложенных циклов, но прибавит гемора с высвобождением ресурсов. Да и ветвистость для понимания тяжелее будет.

Comment: Стремление сделать один return часто порождает монструозные конструкции, которые сложно читать.

Comment: В меру всё хорошо! В меру!!! Большое количество return ов тоже сложно читать. ** ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ** результат работы функции лучше возвращать в одном месте, а не через одно место :-)

Answer (score 2):

1-й вариант всяко-разно лучше, причем по всем параметрам. Мне по барабану этот ваш Дейкстра - BTW: WTF?

1. Экономнее в плане проверок
2. Изящнее
3. Прозрачнее

Единственное его можно только улучшить вариантом предложенным [@Чад](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4), при условии, что `checkConstrains()` еще где-то вызывается.

Answer (score 2):

Второй.
код читабельнее. `else if` это не вложенные условия. Многократного `return` лучше избегать в середине метода, тем более `void` метода. Ни о каком изяществе в 1м варианте речи не идет.
Не знаю, какие у Вас задачи, но если Ваш код будут читать другие, подумайте в первую очередь о том чтоб все было красиво. Java все равно не самый заточенный под экономию ресурсов инструмент, другие е цели.
А что касается производительности, не вижу различий, может кто объяснит?

Answer (score 0):

Производительность нужно измерять ПОСЛЕ того, как код написан. Не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией. Это относится к ЛЮБОМУ языку программирования.

Поймите, что на процессорах Intel может быть хорошо для производительности, для AMD окажется смерти подобно. Только профилировщик, только оборудование, на котором будет работать система. В случаи Java еще и одна и та же версия JVM. Если этот метод не является горячей точкой(hot spot/point), заниматься такой мелочной оптимизацией не стоит - ваш код больше будут читать, на этом и сконцентрируйтесь. В этом данном конкретном случаи лучше один return.

Еще момент. Не используйте в Java процедурный стиль. Пользователь jmu дал вам хороший образец кода.

Comment: Только вот образец @jmu (IMHO хороший код) имеет **несколько** return и безусловно написан в процедурном стиле (что, кстати, проще читается большинством программистов).

Comment: Что на счет процедурного стиля не совсем согласен. Для меня процедурный код в ООП - это 15 приватных методов, которые вызываются друг из друга, не принимая значений и ничего не возвращая. Оттестировать невозможно, рефакторить утомительно. Так что вариант @jmu для меня выглядит как ООП :)
Первый листинг с одним return

Answer (score 0):

Что касается производительности - тут не от самого кода зависит, а от того, как он компонуется и выполняется, то есть надо тестировать, причём на разных Java машинах, как и на разном железе, может быть разный результат. По идее return потяжелее, так как идёт неявный вызов функции, присвоения переменных и т.д.

Что касается написания - обычно проверяются граничные условия (по которым можно сделать выход), а остальное часто вписывается в конструкцию switch.

Answer (score 0):

Сам пишу в первом стиле (на разных языках) и пока проблем ни с чем не возникало.

Comment: Я в основном тоже. Проверяю, return(ы) или goto, потом собственно алгоритм.